# Restore Failed : Failed with an unknown error

Tags: hard-drive, backup, restore

I am trying to restore my data to a new hard drive from my old hard drive. I created a backup on the old hard drive. When I restore it gives me the error "Restore Failed: Failed with an unknown error". What should I do to fix this?

Here is a screen shot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fc08.png]